# OpenCV Object Detection and Splitting, clustering?

Tags: java, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm currently working on an application that will split a scanned image (that contains multiple receipts) into individual receipt images.

Below is the sample image:

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB7lw.jpg)

I was able to detect the edges of each receipts in the scanned image using canny function of OpenCV.

Below is the sample image with detected edges:

[sample image with detected edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP3w0.jpg)

... and the sample code is

```
    Mat src = Highgui.imread(filename);
    Mat gray = new Mat();

    int threshold = 12;

    Imgproc.cvtColor(src, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.blur(gray, gray, new Size(3, 3));
    Imgproc.Canny(gray, gray, threshold, threshold * 3, 3, true);

    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

    Imgproc.findContours(gray, contours, hierarchy,
            Imgproc.RETR_CCOMP,
            Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    if (hierarchy.size().height > 0 && hierarchy.size().width > 0) {
        for (int idx = 0; idx >= 0; idx = (int) hierarchy.get(0, idx)[0]) {
            Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(idx));
            Core.rectangle(src, new Point(rect.x, rect.y),
                    new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                    new Scalar(255, 0, 0));
        }
    }
```

Now my problem is, I don't know how am I going to identify the 3rd receipt since unlike with the first 2 it is not enclosed in one rectangular shape which I will use as the basis for splitting the image.

I've heard that for me to extract the 3rd image, I must use a clustering algorithm like DBSCAN, unfortunately I can't find one.

Anyone knows how am I going to identify the 3rd image?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to use a high pass filter in order to boost the high frequency components(i.e. edges) ? Although visibly there's no edge, there must be some remnants of the receipt's edge which can be enhanced.

Comment: Is this OpenCV 3 Java? Can I see all the code?